# Unable to hide htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, apache, redhat

I'm having a difficult time hiding my .htaccess file --  I double-checked to ensure the following was present in httpd.conf:

```
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Other allow/deny directives on directories are working and the directives in the visible .htaccess file are working.

We are running Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.3 (Santiago) and Apache/2.2.15.

**My question:** Aside from the obvious of, "Why is the .htaccess file still visible?" Is there some other directive that would override this directive or might I have a module missing? (I would think apache would throw an error if this were the case.)

I restarted apache after any changes to this file and even rebooted as a sanity check. I also made some other changes to this file to ensure that I was working on the correct configuration file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you taken a look at [`How <Directory>, <Location> and <Files> sections work`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/sections.html)? It seems that there might be another directive (probably `Location`) evaluated later, which overrides your `Files` directive. It's hard to diagnose more without further details of your Apache configuration.

Comment: You got it -- thanks, Perleone.  I misunderstood how the Location directive worked.  There was a <Location /> directive farther down the httpd.conf file that had allow, deny which, as you said, overrode the File directive declared previously. Thanks for the push in the right direction.